# Kick any user that has been idle for more than an hour on Linux Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-server

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
  # Extract the username and idle time
  username=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
  idle=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $4}')

  idle=$(echo "$idle" | sed 's/^0*//')

  idle_seconds=$((idle*60))

  last_active=$((now-idle_seconds))

  one_hour_ago=$((now-3600))

  if [ "$idle_seconds" -gt 3600 ] && [ "$last_active" -lt "$one_hour_ago" ]; then
    pkill -kill -t "$username"
  fi
done < <(w -h)
```

This is what I have so far but it does not seem to be extracting the idle time correctly. I get this error:

```
line 16: 9:47: syntax error in expression (error token is ":47")
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks. (My server is running Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: cross-posted as https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/735763/330217

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you have a response here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735763/how-to-kick-users-that-have-been-idle-for-more-than-an-hour-in-linux/735764#735764

Answer (score -1):

Not addressing the error you're seeing, but trying to enforce the 1 hour idle problem without scripting.

Create a file under `/etc/profile.d/` (as root):

```
echo "export TMOUT=3600" > /etc/profile.d/tmout.sh
```